# Google Calendar gadget 401 error

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I'm using the Google Calendar gadget (from Labs).  However, when I try to load up my calendar, nothing appears.  Using Firebug, I've noticed that I'm getting `401 Token expired` when trying to access it.  Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Rather than edit the title and question to show how you solved the issue, you should probably add an answer and accept it. (Alternatively, since it was such a trivial solution, you may want to delete this entire question.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to log out and then log back in to your account.